# Cache.manifest in ASP.NET Web Forms - Working offline

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, offline-caching

very new to ASP.NET Web Forms but ok with the others. Im just curious what the equivalent to "cache.manifest" in ASP.NET WebForms?

Thank you

ps. I was looking into <%@ OutputCache Duration="60" VaryByParam="*" %>
am i on the right lines? if so, can you explain? thanks

Answer (score 0):

`cache.manifest` is a feature of HTML5 and separate from HTTP and ASP.NET caching.

You can still use `cache.manifest` in ASP.NET Web Forms.

Comment: how do I use it in ASP.NET Web Forms? It seems to be all about <asp:Content.....>

Comment: Nominally you would just output the required markup just like pure HTML, however some web controls probably won't take kindly to it you'd have to try it on a case by case basis.

Comment: I'll pass on this article for you as well - http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2011/01/26/creating-html5-offline-web-applications-with-asp-net